# Photos uploaded via C# SDK has no "Like" button

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am building an application where users will upload photos which will be stored in an album on their Facebook account. Currently, I am using the C# SDK to achieve this, and I managed to get the photo uploaded.

When I tried to query the photo using the following FQL in the Graph API explorer:

```
select object_id, like_info from photo where object_id=[my_object_id]
```

I get the following result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "object_id": "11111111111111111", 
            "like_info": {
                "can_like": false, 
                "like_count": 0, 
                "user_likes": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Uploading a photo by posting directly to the Graph API endpoint   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=[my_access_token]` and doing a FQL on the resulting ID gives the same result - the `can_like` has a value of `false`. On both occasions, the "Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline?" setting for the app was set to "Public".

If I view the photo page, I can see the photo but there are no `"Like"` or `"Comment"` buttons. Upon further investigation, I found that the "Like" and "Commment" buttons will only appear if I (or rather my access token's user) is a friend of the uploader. Is it possible to make the uploaded photo `"Likeable"?` My objective is to allow users who come to my app to be able to "Like" the individual photos without having to be a friend of the person who uploaded it. Can this be achieved or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is restriction of facebook, but i have found a workaround, when user have their subscriptions enabled here: https://www.facebook.com/about/subscribe anyone can like/comment their photos...